# seaborn: common_norm in displot affecting not only row/col, but also hue?

Tags: python, seaborn, histogram, facet-grid, displot

I want to plot a histogram of percentages using `displot` in seaborn (version 0.12.0), which creates a FacetGrid of subplots. Percentages should be separately calculate for each subplot. In general, one can achieve this using the parameter `common_norm=False`. However, when also adding a hue to the plot, the common_norm also affects the hue categories, which I do not want, because it results in bins summing up to more than 100% within one subplot:

[image: displot with common_norm=False]
You can use this to reproduce the figure:

```py
sns.displot(data=sns.load_dataset("tips"), x="tip", col="smoker", row="time", hue="sex", common_norm=False, common_bins=False, facet_kws=dict(margin_titles=True, sharey="row"), stat="percent")
```

My expected behaviour would be that all the bins within one subplot sum up to 100%.

Is there a way to disable the common_norm on the FacetGrid subplot level, but not on the hue-level?

---

@JohanC: I could not find anything on what `common_norm` should specifically affect, which is why I asked this question, but it does not do what you say:
[image: displot with common_norm=False]

```py
sns.displot(data=sns.load_dataset("tips"), x="tip", col="smoker", row="time", hue="sex", common_norm=True, common_bins=False, facet_kws=dict(margin_titles=True), stat="percent")
```

When setting `common_norm=True`, now the values over the whole FacetGrid sum up to 100%.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Apart from missing reproducible data (e.g. one of seaborn's test data sets), your question also lacks the parameters you used to call `sns.displot`. It could also help to mention the seaborn version (preferably you use the latest one).  The `common_norm` parameter is supposed to only affect one subplot at a time, taking into account the hue, not the row/col.

Comment: @JohanC sorry, please check my edit of the question. I was not aware of the importance of my question's reproducibility or the availability of generic test data sets (it's my first seaborn/python-related question, so please indulge me). I have also responded to your claim that it only affects one subplot at a time.